# Ant task to check that xml node exists in xml file

Tags: ant, ant-contrib, xmltask

I have xml file inside that I want to add xml say

```
<car name="BMW">
   <color>Red</color>
   <model>x3</model>
   </car>
```

I wish to check if  node already exists then I want to update this otheriwse wanted to add new.

I am very new to ant xmltask so my question might be very simple.

With regards,
Avinash Nigam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using an additional root tag `<foo></foo>` for your example (needed for insert operation),
 with xmltask you may use =

```
<!-- edit file in place, use other dest if you need to create a new file -->
<xmltask source="path/to/file.xml" dest="path/to/file.xml">
<!-- create property if car node with name='BMW' exists -->
<copy path="//car[@name='BMW']/text()" property="modelexists"/>
<!-- insert new car node if car node with name='BMW' doesn't exist -->
<insert path="/foo" unless="modelexists">
 <![CDATA[
 <car name="BMW">
  <color>Red</color>
  <model>x3</model>
 </car>
 ]]>
</insert>
<!-- replace car node if car node with name='BMW' exists -->
<replace path="//car[@name='BMW']" if="modelexists">
 <![CDATA[
 <car name="BMW">
  <color>Blue</color>
  <model>x4</model>
 </car>
 ]]>
</replace>
</xmltask>
```